# Como Construir um Explorador de arquivos com PHP?

Tags: php, arquivo

Eu fiz um sistema de Banimento que Cria um arquivo na pasta "bans" com o nome dos users banidos.
Estou construindo um outro sistema pra tirar o ban, mas está muito manual :/

É possível exibir o conteúdo dessa pasta em específico, para que eu possa ter acesso à essa lista de bans? Um exemplo de como fazer essa exibição seria muito apreciado

Comment: É possível sim. Inclusive, tem uma configuração bem padrão no Apache que torna a página muito semelhante a essa aqui: http://maven.totalcross.com/artifactory/repo1-release/ ; creio, no entanto, que você queira, também, gerenciar seus banimentos, excluindo e acrescentando banimentos pela própria página, correto? Se sim, então a opção padrão não seria o suficiente para tal, seria necessário codificar um pouco

Comment: É um arquivo por usuário? Tipo, se o arquivo com o nome do usuário existe, ele está banido?
Aí ficaria uma lista com todos os arquivos, onde você pudesse escolher qual banir ou desbanir, certo?

Comment: opendir()   http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.opendir.php